# How to Deploy Grafana dashboard with side car and group the dashboard with specific dashboards Folder

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

Could you please let me know, How should I deploy a grafana dashboard with sidecar and place/group it in specific dashboard folder?

Example ( Mongo DB dashboard resides in Mongo Folder and Postgres at Postgres Folder). Please note that I am NOT talking about file locations ( /tmp/dashboards ).

I am using the grafana stable HELM chart and latest version of grafana (version 6.4.2)

I am deploying JSON dashboards with k8s configmap and label the config map with sidecar dashboard label. Once deployed it always goes to default "General" dashboards Folder.

HRLM values

```
  sidecar:
    dashboards:
      enabled: true
      label: grafana_dashboard
```

THANKS

Answer (score 7):

You can add dashboard Providers to your values file and specify custom configurations for each of your folders.

You can check the default values for Grafana chart to find an [example](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L525).

The `dashboardProviders` should be under `grafana`, same indentions as `sidecar`.

Example :

```
grafana:
  dashboardProviders:
    dashboardproviders.yaml:
      apiVersion: 1
      providers:
      - name: folder1
        orgId: 1
        type: file
        folder: folder1
        allowUiUpdates: true
        disableDeletion: false
        updateIntervalSeconds: 10
        editable: true
        options:
          path: /tmp/dashboards/folder1
      - name: folder2
        orgId: 1
        type: file
        folder: folder2
        allowUiUpdates: true
        disableDeletion: false
        updateIntervalSeconds: 10
        editable: true
        options:
          path: /tmp/dashboards/folder2
      - name: folder3
        orgId: 1
        type: file
        folder: folder3
        allowUiUpdates: true
        disableDeletion: false
        updateIntervalSeconds: 10
        editable: true
        options:
          path: /tmp/dashboards/folder3
```

Then you can add an annotation to each of your dashboards configmaps to tell helm chart where to place those dashboards :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: name-of-dashboard
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1" #
  annotations:
    k8s-sidecar-target-directory: /tmp/dashboards/folder1
```

This annotation will tell helm to place the target dashboards under /tmp/dashboards/folder1 so that they can be managed by folder1 provider.

Comment: orgId value must be same. for example 1